# No action is perform on button click

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am trying to make multiple buttons in PHP. I am new to html and PHP. I am unable to saw the problem in the code. Its not giving error but do nothing when I click on the button.
Here is the piece of my code

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <table> 
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <table border="5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" margin-bottom="1px" width="100%" style="color:navy"> 
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
     <td> <b> Teacher's Name </b> </td> 
     <td> <b> Courses </b> </td> 
     <td> <b> Feedback </b> </td> 
    </tr> 
    <!--?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($subjects)) {
                $Teacher_Names = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM teachers where Teacher_ID = $row[1]");
                $Name = mysql_fetch_row($Teacher_Names)?--> 
    <tr> 
     <td> 
      <!--?php  echo $Name[0];?--></td> 
     <td> 
      <!--?php echo $row[0];  ?--> </td> 
     <td> 
      <form method="POST" action="CourseFeedbackForm.php"> 
       <img type="button" src="books.jpg" height="30" width="30" id="<?php $button.$count?>" name="submit" value="<?php $row[1]?>"> 
       <!--?php $count = $count + 1; ?--> 
       <img src="horizontal1.jpg" height="30" style="padding-left:0px"> 
       <img type="button" src="teachers.jpg" height="30" width="30" id="<?php $button.$count?>" name="submit" value="<?php $row[1]?>"> 
       <!--?php $count = $count + 1; ?-->  
      </form></td>  
    </tr> 
    <!--?php } ?--> 
   </tbody>
  </table>    
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Naming it "submit" doesn't turn a simple button into a submit button...

Comment: So what should be done ?

Comment: Definitely learn the basics of HTML or this will be the first of a long list of questions...

Answer (score 0):

It kind of took me a while to understand what you are doing there, but not I still did not understand everything. Why are you calling `<img type="button">`? In order to get a button, you know, that thing that you can click and it executes a piece of code, use `<button type="submit"></button>`. Almost everything you've done there is wrong. I'm not an expert, but I really can't see the reason you would try to use the `<img>` tag to create a button.

Offtopic: Learn to use `<div></div>`. It is much more flexible than a table, and table's are old and outdated.

Comment: Okay.I think I should spend more time on it.